# Comment permission by role and content type

Tags: 7, users, comments

I have different roles (e.g. A, B, C) and I have different contents in a menu (e.g. A, B, C).

I want that only the user A can post/edit comments on content A,  and not on B and C.

So I don't know what module can help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is [Comment Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm) module.
**Some description of this module**

> The Comment Permissions module enables control of commenting by user
>   role and by node type. Additional user permissions for selected node
>   types are added to the user access system so you can configure
>   commenting with more control than Drupal core provides.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) will be flexible enough to do what you want.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

It has a per-node setting so you allow role-level access to each piece of content you want to restrict.